# pandas: How to work with _iLocIndexer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.16.1'
>>> s1 = pd.Series([1, 3, 5], index=list('abc'))
>>> s1.iloc(0)
<pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer object at 0x10ca3f690>
```

I expected the integer 1 to be returned for `s1.iloc(0)`, but got an `_iLocIndexer` object instead.  What can I do with this object?  How do I work with it?

Comment: square brackets:  `[0]` not `(0)`

Answer (score 29):

The solution, due to @JohnE, is to use square brackets `[0]` instead of `(0)` with `iloc`.

Some more info after digging through some pandas code.

`s1.iloc` makes `iloc` look like a method.  But it is an attribute and the value of the attribute is `_iLocIndexer`.  `_iLocIndexer` is callable with arguments and it returns a copy of itself ignoring any args or kwargs (see pandas.core.indexing._NDFrameIndexer.**call** in pandas code).  This is why `s1.iloc(0)` is a valid call.

When `s1.iloc[0]` is called with square brackets, an `_iLocIndexer` is instantiated and the call to `[]` operator results in a call to the `iLocIndexer`'s `getitem' method.

The same is true for the other indexers - `loc`, `ix`, `at` and `iat`.  These indexers are installed using `setattr` in class method pandas.core.generic.NDFrame._create_indexer.