# How to loop through pandas data frame to extract specific rows and selected columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have Whole_mat as pandas df. corpus_index as valid rows that I want to copy into New_mat, and I want only column numbers 1, 4, and 7. But order should be 7, 1, 4. Below is what I tried but I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Whole mat shape is, say,  Nx10, I want nx3 for New_mat.

```
New_mat = []
for i in range(len(corpus_index):
    index = corpus_index[i]
    New_mat.append(Whole_mat[[index], [7,1,4]])
print New_mat
```

What could be a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Probably you should use `New_mat.append(Whole_mat.loc[index, [7,1,4]])` If you have 7, 1, 4 as column names

Comment: That is throwing errro "'None of [[7, 1, 4]] are in the [columns]'" . Do I have to give column names as string? like [ "user_id", "phone_no" ] ?

Comment: Yes, you should. You could also pass `columns` with `New_mat.append(Whole_mat.loc[index, Whole_mat.columns[7,1,4]])`. *Note* index started from 0.

Comment: Pardon me for asking silly questions but its easy for me :/. I am getting `too many indices for array` for the same line `New_mat.append(Whole_mat.loc[index, Whole_mat.columns[7,1,4]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is simple indexing. Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(10) for _ in xrange(10)])

In [4]: df.ix[[1,4,5],[3,4,5]]
Out[4]:
          3         4         5
1  0.523302  0.104327  0.672953
4  0.303693  0.785685  0.080759
5  0.955738  0.987779  0.410638
```

More info here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

And whenever you are using pandas, avoid "looping" as much as possible (it isn't necessary very often). The whole purpose of using pandas is vectorization.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will learn it. I used above method, and got `<pandas.core.indexing._IXIndexer at 0x7fab62a734d0>`. Now what object is New_mat? How can I use it. I tried New_mat.head(), print New_mat, but nothing is helping.

Comment: You probably used `.ix()` and not `.ix[]`. You need brackets, not parenthesis.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. But what's difference between `.ix() and .ix[]`?

Comment: Not quite sure what's the use of that `pandas.core.indexing._IXIndexer ` object. Some more info here in case you are curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447719/pandas-how-to-work-with-ilocindexer
Also, if this solved your problem, please accept it as valid answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to iterate using for loop, you could try doing this,

```
New_mat = Whole_mat.loc[corpus_index.index, Whole_mat.columns[[7, 1, 4]]]
```

Note: columns indices start from 0.

Comment: You generally don't need to loop through rows of  a dataframe, and more importantly you *shouldn't*, since it's usually much slower than using the vectorized operations that are built in to pandas.