# How to get selected row with columns of dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, split

My main idea is separating data in dataframe with multiple columns and rows into training dataset and test dataset.

**Edited: I want to use same train and test data everytime. I am trying to avoid random choices.**

I have tried this:

```
def splitTestandTrainData(datavalues):

    #create new dataframe with columns
    testDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=datavalues.columns)

    #select every 4th row as a test data
    for i in range(1,len(datavalues.rows),4):

        #getting single row with all columns
        testDataFrame.append(datavalues.iloc(i))

        #and delete
        dataValues.drop(dataValues.index[i])
```

but I cant append row into new dataframe. Im also not sure If it is correct way. How can I do that?

And my other question is What if we want to do it with selected columns? I mean how we can append column with rows into empty dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that manually.
Use sklearn's [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for it.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5) # your input features and target value
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

If you want to do it with selected columns, harness the power of pandas and select only specific columns before performing train test split.

```
X = df[['col1', 'col2']]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am trying to avoid randomness. So I want excatly the same test and training values. This function choses test values for randomly.

Comment: If you pass same value to random_state (42 above) it will return same rows under train and test divisions.

Comment: Oh thank you it works in this case but still I didnt get my answer on how can I append row

Comment: append rows in empty dataframe? or this _And my other question is What if we want to do it with selected columns? I mean how we can append column with rows into empty dataframe?_
I have provided the solution to select columns, it will return a dataframe with just those columns.

Comment: [here](https://thispointer.com/pandas-how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-and-append-rows-columns-to-it-in-python/) is a nice tutorial on how you can append rows in an empty dataframe.
Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) of append, it expects a DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these.

Comment: I saw that but the problem is I cant write every columns like this 'User_ID': 23 because I have around 1000 columns Im searching the automatic way to do this.

Comment: You can also append series. `testDataFrame.append(datavalues.iloc(i))` isn't that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do something like that but It gives me error.

Comment: testDataFrame.append(dataValues.iloc(i)) in this line I got: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: When I change into this: testDataFrame.append(pd.Series(dataValues.iloc(i))) 
I got: TypeError: object of type '_iLocIndexer' has no len()

Comment: Don't use `()` with iloc, use square brackets `[]`.
For further understanding, read the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447719/pandas-how-to-work-with-ilocindexer) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas.DataFrame.sample()

testDataFrame = datavalues.sample(frac=0.25)

will return a random sample of 25% of the original rows.  There are many other options for the random sampling.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I want same test values everytime so I can compare the other results. I am trying to avoid randomness.